# how to get focusout event for .editor-text of slickgrid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid with editable cells and when i dbclick cells in grid a input box with .editor-text is shown. when i click on other cells onBeforeEditorDestory method is triggered before destroying editor(i.e., remove input box and add its value to cell), but when i click out side the grid input box focuses out but editor wont destroy. in jquery we have

```
`$('.editor-text').on('blur', function(){
      // do something here...
})`
```

, but how do i do this in angularJS and how do i destroy editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the directive [`ngBlur`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) to trigger an expression to evaluate on `blur`

```
<input name="editor" id="editor" ng-blur="doSomething()" ng-model="editorText"/>
```

Comment: but i need this particular directive in a slickgrid.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. and for my other question how to destroy active editor on slick grid, we need to use `commitCurrentEdit()` method.